Best design pattern to synchronize local and cloud databases?
Right now I have an edge device (resource constrained) which is processing, storing, and querying time series data using a Postgres DB.
When a data collection event has ended, a simple script on the device does the following steps:

Copies the local database tables to CSVs.
Inserts (on conflict do nothing) the CSVs to a cloud backup database with the same migration applied.
Clears the tables of the local databse to save resources.

This very simple process has been hindering growth in the database use complexity, as now schemas must stay in sync and unique keys not UUID-derived cause collisions, etc.
Is there a convention for how to organize this sync process?
I was thinking of moving away from the idea the databases should be identical, and rather then export a CSV via psql commands there would be a proper coded translation layer to interpret and translate every data point from each database simultaneously.  My goal however is a more low level process that is more resilient to schema changes and will protect the integrity of the cloud database's data.
Any ideas are much appreciated.  I feel like I am missing a architectural method or doing something wrong.

Do you want to synchronize, backup, or archive the data? Each option would use different approaches. Is the clound database multi tenant? Does the cloud database also require processing, querying etc? Is the data ever changed after it has been added?

This is an archive setup I would say.  The data on the cloud is query only, and will recieve considerable query traffic.  The only write modification to the cloud database is done when a backup/archive event is done, and that can be guarranteed to be done by only one user, one at a time.

Databases should not be identical. There should be an API that accepts data, verifies it, transforms and pushes to the remote database. There are multiple benefits of that. Like for example you can run different client versions, with different data format and still have unified database on the other side.

I think the word 'synchronize' is incorrect here. That doesn't align with what you are describing.  If they were synchronized, you would have the same data in both databases.  You should probably read some articles on the CAP Theorem as well, if you are not already familiar with the idea.

This is a very interesting design. It is however illusory to keep the central and the local database always in sync.  You can try to reduce the desynchronisation, but the universe will be against you with network latency, concurrent edge devices, and physical limitations. Accepting that both databases are not always in sync could help to achieve a more robust design:

The saga pattern based on eventual consistency could help you to overcome your current limitations.  More precisely, I'd consider a choreography based saga, where each participant pushes the events and respond to events it subscribed.

While you could use your current CSV based approach to exchange between the edge and the cloud, you could consider using a staging area on the cloud database for the new datasets + with a batch descriptor that will serve as "event" emulation.

A more robust and secure approach would be to migrate to an architecture using a midleware for communicating events, e.g. using some kafka messaging (the edge publishes messages consumed by the cloud service, and vice-versa).


While the edge aims for local processing and analytics,  another question would be to know if you really need all the data of the cloud replicated on the edge, or only those related directly or indirectly to the local matters of the edge device. A more hybrid approach could be considered,  where cloud and edge would not just be replicas, but serve different, complementary purposes.
Additional remark:  In such a decentralised edge/cloud architecture, I find btw that some other microservices patterns could be applicable as well,  since, even if more coarse-grained than microservices, edge/cloud problems have a lot in common with(e.g. each edge device and the cloud have their own db,  there are scalability issues such as avoiding that edge devices monopolises the cloud service and make it crumble under the data load, etc...)

There's a very simple way to resolve the primary key collisions, and that is to use a composite key on the server that stores both the origin of the data and its key which was assigned at the origin.
In terms of the schemas staying in sync, obviously there needs to be some kind of correspondence if there isn't to be data loss. But I wouldn't proceed on the assumption that they will always be 100% aligned, unless the entire system is under your control and you can readily access all parts at leisure.
If you need to use a database engine for reliability reasons, and for the transfer to be confirmed before deleting the data at source, then you'd probably want a system of staging tables, maybe one per device or certainly something that allows you to receive the data without immediately having to reconcile it into the combined store.
Algorithms, schedules, and supervision can become complicated though when real reliability is required. If best-efforts will do, simply sending the CSV across as a file (including the version of the schema or protocol being used by the edge device), then processing at leisure according to what that particular version needs, would be sufficient.
There's usually more than one "edge device" in a system with such a notion, and you don't want every change requiring simultaneous updates to the whole thing.
